# Convert chr to date using as.date

Tags: r, time-series, as.date

```
      "2008/3"  "2008/4"  "2008/5"  "2008/6"  "2008/7"  "2008/8"  "2008/9"  "2008/10"
  [9] "2008/11" "2008/12" "2009/1"  "2009/2"  "2009/3"  "2009/4"  "2009/5"  "2009/6" 
 [17] "2009/7"  "2009/8"  "2009/9"  "2009/10" "2009/11" "2009/12"
```

I use `as.Date(data$Time,format='%Y/%m')` and it coerce to NAs.

Comment: I tried a for loop like this"for (i in date$Month){ if(i<10){i=paste0("0",i)}}" and it cannot change 2008/3 to be 2008/03

Comment: `as.Date(paste0("2000/3", "/1"), format = "%Y/%m/%d")`.  Also see `as.yearmon` in the zoo package for representing objects having year and month without day.

Comment: Like @G.Grothendieck said `as.yearmon` does it, you have to replace the `/`for `-` though.

Answer (score 3):

try with this

```
as.Date(paste(data$Time,1,sep="/"),format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

It should be working

Comment: `format(as.Date(paste(data$Time,1,sep="/"),format='%Y/%m/%d'), "%Y/%m")` is probably closer to the desired output though.

Comment: @nate.edwinton this returns character datatype

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @G. Grothendieck `as.yearmon()` does the job. Try:

```
dates <- c("2008/3", "2008/4", "2008/5", "2008/6", "2008/7", "2008/8",
           "2008/9", "2008/10", "2008/11")
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(dates, "%Y/%m")
# [1] "mars 2008"  "avr. 2008"  "mai 2008"   "juin 2008"  "juil. 2008"
# [6] "août 2008"  "sept. 2008" "oct. 2008"  "nov. 2008"
# or
as.Date(as.yearmon(dates, "%Y/%m"))
# [1] "2008-03-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-05-01" "2008-06-01" "2008-07-01"
# [6] "2008-08-01" "2008-09-01" "2008-10-01" "2008-11-01"
```